# How to remove symbol collision between .so and .o files

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, symbols

I am trying to build an executable which links a .so library and some .o files. 
This .so file has some common symbols with  a .o file. I am not pretty sure if there is a way to change symbols inside the .so file. If there exists, can anyone tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Symbols for .so live in different address spaces. .o Files are generated objects. You cannot statically link to an so, you probably linked to a symbols library. Where do you get errors ?

Comment: While running the executable, I get an error "symbol lookup error : .../some.so" : undefined symbol : _ZSomeSymbol.

Comment: Was the .so compiled for the machine/environement you are running it on ?

Comment: If possible, change the symbols in the .o files to be file "static" so the names are not visible outside the .o file.

Comment: Another option is to use a namespace in your .o file.

Comment: Earlier, I used to link .a file. There, I used to change the symbol names in the archive file. But I am having trouble in doing the same for .so file. Therefore, trying to find a way out for that.

Comment: MichaelCMS: Machine was different definitely. This comes from a different company. Then we integrate that with out product/

Comment: Brian : I am afraid, I cannot do that. These symbols are used by other code as well. Adding namespace would make the change very compllicated, since the code base is greater than 3GB